# How to have a UICollectionView load everything over again

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

so I'm currently busy with a Diary app.
When you go to the second view (the add a day view) with the following code:

```
- (void)goToAddDayView
{
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *ViewController = (UIViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addDay"];
[self presentViewController:ViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

It pops up a view where you can add a day, perfect.
But when I submit the day and go back to my first view, a UICollectionView.
It doesn't load the new day I currently added.
I'm using a NSArray with NSUserdefaults.
For the items in section method I use a variable called Items that also updates with +1 when you add a new day. (using NSUserDefaults)

**So how do I let a UICollectionView reload all cells and stuff?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger it in `viewWillAppear`, `UICollectionView` has a `reloadData` method which should work right out of the box, given you appear to be doing everything else by the standards.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `reloadData` in your `viewWillAppear:` like:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated
{
    [yourCollectionView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work, I used a IBOutlet on my CollectionView called cView and tried [cView reloadData]; in the viewWillAppear method, but it still doesn't reload anything. Do I need to use a UICollectionViewController? Because right now I'm using a UIViewController with inside of the view a collection view to add a toolbar and stuff what I really need.

Comment: Try NSLog of something in viewWillAppear to confirm it's being called. Maybe output how many elements are in your array. If it isn't increasing, something is wrong somewhere. You might be adding an element to a copy of the array rather than the array itself.

Comment: Thanks I fixed it! I forgot, I had all my update NSArray in my ViewDidLoad, I have now put it in my viewWillAppear and everything works. Thanks!